# Unable to send amount below one (.x) in Mac OS and Windows OS GUI

Tags: monero-wallet-gui

(Primary enviornment Mac OS 10.13.6, running local node, completly synced)
I updated my GUI after the fork and successfully completed one transaction. 
Two weeks later, I attempt to open the GUI and it wont load.  I found an update which was downloaded and installed. I kept all previous blockchain headers, wallet info, etc, opened the new GUI, wallet and daemon proceeded to sync quickly. My previous balance was visible.  I was sent more XMR and it was recived and unlocked.

I attempted to make a small test transaction (.1) to a known working address (friend's address), and the send button is greyed out.  The box around the address shows it is a valid address (no red box).

I installed the GUI on a bootcamp partition of the same mac running Windows 10,(imported blockchain headers from Mac OS) same exact issue.

I tried running a remote node

Am I missing something implimented in the new update?  Anyone else have this issue?  I've spent at least 4 hours so far troubleshooting and researching.  I don't have access to a non-Mac to try running the GUI on.

Comment: Try 0.1  not .1  I read somewhere one needs the leading zero.

Answer (score 1):

An amount below 1 has to be entered as `0.x` and not as `.x` in the GUI. Put differently, the GUI will not accept amounts that are stated as `.x`

Note that we (the GUI contributors) are working on making improvements in this regard.